# Python Post to PHP Post

Tags: python, php

I am wondering if this is possible to make in PHP with curl or file_get_contents.

I have some Python code:

```
    body = json.dumps({
        'agent': {
            'name': 'Minecraft',
            'version': 1
        },
        'username': email,
        'password': password,
        'clientToken': "fff"
    })
            r = requests.post(url="https://authserver.mojang.com/authenticate", headers=header, data=body)
```

What would be the equivelent in CURL? Cause i've tried some variations in PHP but can't get it to work.

PHP Code, that i have tried:

```
$parameters = [
    'agent'    => [
    'name'    => 'Minecraft',
    'version' => 1
    ],
    'username' => $email,
    'password' => $password,
    'clientToken' => 'fff'
];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://authserver.mojang.com/authenticate");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$parameters);  //Post Fields
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$headers = array(
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Content-Type: application/json',
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close ($ch);
```

But i get response:

```
{"error":"JsonParseException","errorMessage":"Unexpected character ('-' (code 45)) in numeric value: expected digit (0-9) to follow minus sign, for valid numeric value\n at [Source: (org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpInputOverHTTP); line: 1, column: 3]"}
```

If anyone has any insight on this please reply on this question!

Comment: You're setting up your details in `$parameters`, but you set `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` to `$vars`. It also looks like you need to send a JSON object, but you're not converting your PHP array to JSON. There are other possible issues here

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular Yes, but even with it changed to $parameters it still isn't working correctly.

Comment: Response i get is: {"error":"JsonParseException","errorMessage":"Unexpected character ('-' (code 45)) in numeric value: expected digit (0-9) to follow minus sign, for valid numeric value\n at [Source: (org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpInputOverHTTP); line: 1, column: 3]"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in the creation of the authentication object. You're creating a PHP array (you need an object), and you're not converting to JSON before sending.

Create the authentication object as an object, then use `json_encode()` to create a JSON string, and use that as your payload.

```
<?php

// Display some error s for this development code
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);

// Create the authentication object
$params = (object)[];
$params->agent = (object)['name'=>"MineCraft", 'version'=>'1'];
$params->username = "email";
$params->password='password';
$params->clientToken='fff';

// Now create the payload for cURL to use in its POST
$payload = json_encode($params);

// Set headers to match payload
$headers = array(
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Content-Type: application/json',
);


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://authserver.mojang.com/authenticate");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$payload);  //Post Fields
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);


$response = curl_exec($ch);
$curlInfo = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

// Ok - see what we got.
echo "----------------------------<br>\n";
var_dump($response);
echo "----------------------------<br>\n";
var_dump($curlInfo);
```

This code gives this result:

```
{"error":"ForbiddenOperationException","errorMessage":"Invalid credentials. Invalid username or password."}
```

Since I don't have a user name or password at Mojang this is what I would expect

Comment: @namename If this answers your question please accept the answer by clicking the tick.